# How to get user identifier from Firebase Authentication as a String

Tags: firebase, firebase-realtime-database, swiftui, firebase-authentication

I'm currently working on an app using SwiftUI and working with Firebase to store my user data. My login and registration pages are currently working, but I was wanting to have the user's username display to the profile page upon logging in. The sign in button calls my signIn() function which is part of my ObservableObject that I've been using. Currently, nothing is displayed at all since I initially have the username empty. Any help at all would be appreciated. Let me know if I need to provide more information.

```
func signIn(email: String, password: String) {
        auth.signIn(withEmail: email, password: password) { [weak self]
            result, error in
            guard result != nil, error == nil else {
                return
            }
            DispatchQueue.main.async {
                self?.signedIn = true
            }
        }
        if signedIn {
            username = auth.currentUser!.providerID
            
        }
    }
```

Comment: `auth.signIn(....){...}` is what is called an asynchronous function (look it up).
Because of that, you need to put your `if signedIn {  username = auth.currentUser!.providerID }`
 inside it. Currently the `if signedIn {...}` gets executed well before `auth.signIn(....)` is done, that is
 why you do not get anything for your `username`

Comment: @workingdogsupportUkraine Alright, thanks for the explanation. I did move it inside the auth.SignIn(...), but I am currently getting errors regarding the wrapping of the auth object, and I'm not too familiar with the details of wrapping with ? and ! statements. I tried using the fix feature and ended up with a solution, but I'm not sure how correct it is. Would you happen to know how to address this issue?

Comment: Show the full error messages you get, and on which lines of your code (edit your post with the full code you are using now). Show enough code for us to reproduce your errors.
Also explain what you mean by `...the wrapping of the auth object....`.
Show a minimal reproducible code that produces your issue, see: [minimal code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). 
Without this it is difficult to give you any advice.